# Is it possible to use cognitive search in a local azurite environment

Tags: azure-cognitive-search, azurite

This could entirely be a case of me misunderstanding how Azurite works, but I can't seem to find the answers by searching.

I've downloaded Azurite through the VS code extension, and uploaded some data to a local blob source on my hard drive using Windows Storage Explorer; that's now visible in the azurite `__blobstorage__` folder. I've tried initialising a new function to try and search over the data, but the project i'm working on specifically phrased it as:

> "Set-up local version of Storage and Cognitive Search and index a sample set of documents"

Is this possible to do and i'm just missing something somewhere? Or have I misunderstood the task and you can't actually run cognitive search locally without at some stage attaching to the subscription? I'm waiting for the PM to get back from annual leave, so I thought i'd carry on trying to find out the answer whilst I wait, and hoping someone here might be able to help me out!

I've tried hunting through both the microsoft VS Code Local Development Hot to Guide and the Git repository for Azurite, so i'm not sure if i'm just reading the information wrong or if it's just not there to find.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Azure Search does not currently offer a localhost emulator. Azurite is for localhost storage emulation. It is not possible for an Azure Search Indexer to index data from a local emulator, but you can write data to Azure Search directly via the [Index Docs REST APIs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/searchservice/addupdate-or-delete-documents). You would need to write a script to read from your local storage and make an API call to index the data into a Search instance in Azure.